# Google App Script Randomly Stopped Working - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'streams') (line 6)

Tags: json, google-apps-script, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

This Google Apps Script code to scrape press release news from Yahoo Finance randomly stopped working today.
It suddenly gives the following error -
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'streams') (line 6)

```
function pressReleases(code) {
  var url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+code+'/press-releases'
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/root.App.main = ([\s\S\w]+?);\n/);
  if (!html || html.length == 1) return;
  var obj = JSON.parse(html[1].trim());
  var res = obj.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamStore.streams["YFINANCE:"+code+".mega"].data.stream_items[0].title;
  return res || "No value";
}
```

Code in Cell (with the stock symbol in cell A6)

```
=pressReleases(A6)
```

I can still retrieve JSON using python and the format of the data in the JSON is the exact same so I'm guessing it's a problem with Google Apps Script but I'm having no luck in fixing it.

The JSON output is here: https://privatebin.net/?4064ef5520f5b445#FDiJS868e3xSsgzh3y8LsF72LsefyoZ635kqCx62ZtwH

Any help as to why it suddenly stopped working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your showing script is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69548232)? When I saw the HTML, it seems that in the current stage, the data is converted with the salted base64. In this case, I would like to propose an answer by reflecting on the method of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74872266).

### Usage:

#### 1. Get crypto-js.

Please access https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js. And, copy and paste the script to the script editor of Google Apps Script, and save the script.

#### 2. Modify script.

```js
function pressReleases(code) {
  var url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + code + '/press-releases'
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/root.App.main = ([\s\S\w]+?);\n/);
  if (!html || html.length == 1) return;
  var obj = JSON.parse(html[1].trim());

  // --- I modified the below script.
  const { _cs, _cr } = obj;
  if (!_cs || !_cr) return;
  const key = CryptoJS.algo.PBKDF2.create({ keySize: 8 }).compute(_cs, JSON.parse(_cr)).toString();
  const obj2 = JSON.parse(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(obj.context.dispatcher.stores, key)));
  var res = obj2.StreamStore.streams["YFINANCE:" + code + ".mega"].data.stream_items[0].title;
  // ---

  return res || "No value";
}
```

- When this script is used and `code` is `PGEN`, the value of `Precigen to Present at the 41st Annual J.P. Morgan Healthcare Conference` is obtained.

### Note:

- If you want to directly load `crypto-js`, you can also use the following script. But, in this case, the process cost becomes higher than that of the above flow. Please be careful about this.

  ```
    const cdnjs = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js";
    eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText());
  ```
- **I can confirm that this method can be used for the current situation (December, 21, 2022). But, when the specification in the data and HTML is changed in the future update on the server side, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.**

### Reference:

- [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)

Comment: omg, thank you so much! This part is critical to my strategy but my coding skills are proper novice level - I probably never would have figured that out on my own. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @DarkWingDuck Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I guess that this specification might be changed in the future update on the server side. In that case, please post it as a new question. By this, it will help a lot of users think of a solution.

Comment: Hi there @Tanaike, this solution now returns an empty cell , not an error message and when I run it in the google apps script code edit page I get a "Notice   Execution completed" notification. Any idea how to resolve this? It seems like it's working but having trouble returning the correct value to the cell, could it be an issue with the last line in the code i.e. return res || "No value"; ?

Comment: I've posted the empty cell on execution as a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75114850/google-apps-script-for-yahoo-finance-returns-empty-cell

Answer (score 0):

I believe match returns an array so perhaps you need

```
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/root.App.main = ([\s\S\w]+?);\n/)[index];
```

Oh I missed the fact that your  using it in a conditional on the very next line and then in the next line you're using the index of one.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(html[1].trim());
```

so the problem must be either in a data variation or this line `var res = obj.context.dispatcher.stores.StreamStore.streams["YFINANCE:"+code+".mega"].data.stream_items[0].title;`

Comment: Thanks for replying but that gives me - ReferenceError: index is not defined
pressReleases @ yahoonews.gs:3

Comment: You are supposed to replace the term index with an integer which selects one of the elements of the array ie `0,1,2....`

Comment: I was assuming that you had some knowledge of coding.  Perhaps I was incorrect

Comment: Quite the noob I'm afraid, I tried all the way up to 20, no luck. Cheers for replying though.

Comment: What does html[1] look like?

Comment: I think the rest of the code is fine, apps script returns the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'streams')
pressReleases @ yahoonews.gs:6", so like you said the error is definitely on line 6, around the .streams part

Comment: The JSON output is here if it helps https://privatebin.net/?4064ef5520f5b445#FDiJS868e3xSsgzh3y8LsF72LsefyoZ635kqCx62ZtwH

Comment: It would be useful for others to just paste it into your question.