# Google Apps Script for Yahoo Finance Returns Empty Cell

Tags: json, google-apps-script, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

A previously working solution that was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74836864/google-app-script-randomly-stopped-working-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-o) by @tanaike suddenly returns an empty cell upon execution. I don't get an error message and in the google apps scripts edit page I get "Notice       Execution completed".

It looks like it's working in the background but having trouble returning a value to the cell, my guess would be something wrong with the last line that may resolve it?

```
function pressReleases(code) {
  var url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + code + '/press-releases'
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/root.App.main = ([\s\S\w]+?);\n/);
  if (!html || html.length == 1) return;
  var obj = JSON.parse(html[1].trim());

  // --- I modified the below script.
  const { _cs, _cr } = obj;
  if (!_cs || !_cr) return;
  const key = CryptoJS.algo.PBKDF2.create({ keySize: 8 }).compute(_cs, JSON.parse(_cr)).toString();
  const obj2 = JSON.parse(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(obj.context.dispatcher.stores, key)));
  var res = obj2.StreamStore.streams["YFINANCE:" + code + ".mega"].data.stream_items[0].title;
  // ---

  return res || "No value";
}
```

The CryptoJS code saved as a script in google apps script is [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js)

Comment: "Any ideas..." like question are not a good fit for this site. Questions on this site should be about a spedific programming problem. Ref. [help/on-topic]. Once said that, you should have to spend some time learning how the script included in the question work and about [tag:web-scraping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tested this script, at `if (!_cs || !_cr) return;`, I confirmed that the values of `_cs` and `_cr` are `undefined`. From this result, I understood that recently, the specification of the key for decrypting the data has been changed at the server side. When I saw [this thread](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1291), I confirmed the same situation. In the thread, I noticed that, in the current stage, the key can be simply retrieved from the HTML data. So, as with the current script, how about the following modification?

### Usage:

#### 1. Get crypto-js.

Please access https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js. And, copy and paste the script to the script editor of Google Apps Script, and save the script.

#### 2. Modify script.

```js
function pressReleases(code) {
  var url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + code + '/press-releases'
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().match(/root.App.main = ([\s\S\w]+?);\n/);
  if (!html || html.length == 1) return;
  var obj = JSON.parse(html[1].trim());
  var key = Object.entries(obj).find(([k]) => !["context", "plugins"].includes(k))[1];
  if (!key) return;
  const obj2 = JSON.parse(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.stringify(CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(obj.context.dispatcher.stores, key)));
  var res = obj2.StreamStore.streams["YFINANCE:" + code + ".mega"].data.stream_items[0].title;

  // console.log(res); // Check the value in the log.
  return res || "No value";
}
```

- When this script is run with `code = "PGEN"`, the value of `Precigen Provides Pipeline and Corporate Updates at the 41st Annual J.P. Morgan Healthcare Conference` is obtained.

### Note:

- If you want to load `crypto-js directly`, you can also use the following script. But, in this case, the process cost becomes higher than that of the above flow. Please be careful about this.

  ```js
  const cdnjs = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText());
  ```
- **I can confirm that this method can be used for the current situation (January 14, 2023). But, when the specification in the data and HTML is changed in the future update on the server side, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.**

### Reference:

- [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)

Comment: Thank you bro,it works! That's been an immense help, and will no doubt help many others too. Much appreciated.