# dividend error on Google Sheets with the function IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets, stock, yahoo-finance

I want to get the dividend of companies like ENG.MC or other stock like GSY.TO, but Sheets did not find the dividend.

i put on my Google Sheet:
=IMPORTXML($D$25;D24)

I want the "Forward Dividend & Yield" from Yahoo but i recieved a #N/A
[example of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejJ9E.png)

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected value. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected value?

Comment: i  uploaded a picture in the pos to show the error

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I think that in this case, the reason for your current issue is due to the data in the HTML is being encrypted by AES. But, fortunately, as the current sample script, I have posted it to [this thead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75250562). I think that this will be useful for retrieving your expected values. Please check it. But, it seems that the server-side often changed the specification of encryption. So, at that time, it is required to think of a new solution. Please be careful about this.